# Is there a way to receive list of collections?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to receive a list of collections in Firebase DB?
I tried via 
Firestore.instance but it does not look Firebase published them

Comment: Are you asking about Firestore, and not Firebase Authentication?

Comment: you right, I updated the question.

Comment: There is no Flutter API (nor any client platform API) to do this.